# How can I integrate $ \int \frac{x^2}{1 + x^3} $?

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int \frac{x^2}{1 + x^3}$$

I found this problem in one of my past papers and didn't understand how the solution to this is $ \frac{1}{3} \ln (1+x^3) $. I would really appreciate it if someone guided me through this. I'm sure this is the answer of the integration because I checked it on WolframAlpha and in the mark scheme, but did not understand how to arrive at the answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to make a substitution?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. Thanks, I'm on it!

Comment: $$\dfrac{d(1+x^3)}{dx}=?$$

Comment: @T. Bongers I'm not getting it even after substitution.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee didn't get you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$u=x^3+1\implies du=3x^2\,dx$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I messed up while taking $ du $. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution has already been covered by Yagna, however it can never hurt to have another method. The method I will take here is without question an extremely overly complicated method for this question, but is good practice for integrals of [rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) as a general method.

Here you have a rational function of the form:

\begin{equation}
 f(x) = \frac{P_n(x)}{Q_m(x)}
\end{equation}

Were $P_n(x)$ and $Q_m(x)$ are real valued polynomials of orders $n$ and $m$ respectively. The first step is to factor $Q_m(x)$. By the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) we can factor $Q_m(x)$ is a product of constant, linear, and quadratic terms. For your question:

\begin{equation} 
f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^3 + 1} \rightarrow P_n(x) = P_2(x) = x^2,\quad Q_m(x) = Q_3(x) = x^3 + 1
\end{equation}

Here $Q_3(x)$ is factored quite easily:

\begin{equation}
Q_m(x) = Q_3(x) = x^3 + 1 = \left(x + 1\right)\left(x^2 - x + 1\right)
\end{equation}

Thus,

\begin{equation}
 f(x) = \frac{x^2}{\left(x + 1\right)\left(x^2 - x + 1\right)}
\end{equation}

We now apply a [Partial Fraction Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) to yield:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{x^2}{\left(x + 1\right)\left(x^2 - x + 1\right)} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{x + 1} -  \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{2x - 1}{x^2 - x + 1}
\end{equation}

And hence,

\begin{align}
 \int  \frac{x^2}{x^3 + 1}\:dx &= \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{x + 1}\:dx +  \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{2x - 1}{x^2 - x + 1}\:dx \\
&= \frac{1}{3}\ln\left|x + 1\right| +  \frac{1}{3} \cdot \ln\left|x^2 - x + 1 \right| + C
\end{align}

Where $C$ is the constant of integration.

As before, this is overly complicated for this exact situation, but it is a process that is useful in tackling these types of integrals.

**Edit** I had an incorrect partial fraction decomposition which was picked by a commenter. Thank you to that person.

Comment: That can't be right, can it? Didn't you notice that your answer is not equal to $\frac13\ln|1+x^3|+$ constant? (Your partial fraction decomposition is wrong.)

Comment: @TonyK - It is indeed. Thank you for the pickup. I will correct.

Comment: I think it should be $\frac{1}{3}\ln\left|x + 1\right| + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \ln\left|x^2 - x + 1 \right|=\frac13\ln|x^3+1|$

Comment: Yes, thank you @TheSimpliFire. Is now corrected.